# Как посмотреть данные отправленные ajax'ом в другом файле?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Из одного файла отправляю данные из формы в другой файл.

```
function call() {
    var mineMsg = $('#mineForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'qqq.php',
        data: mineMsg,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.res').html(data);
            window.location.href = "http://site.ru/qqq";
        },
        error: function(xhr, str) {
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

Код файла qqq.php содержит строку `print_r[$_POST]`. Но после редиректа на него массив POST пустой... Как передать данные из одного файла в другой?

P.S. Атрибуты формы: `<form method="post" id="mineForm" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">`

Comment: Редиректом Вы называете это: `window.location.href = "http://site.ru/qqq";`? Это соответствует запросу GET.

Comment: А как тогда правильно?

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Вы передаете данные AJAXом. А потом зачем то еще и пешком (GETом) идете на эту страницу, уже без данных.

Comment: Объясните, что Вы хотите сделать, и зачем здесь нужен ajax?

Answer (score 1):

По факту в вашем примере идет два запроса.

Сначала через ajax делается POST запрос c данными формы. По факту его успеха делается перенаправление на страницу - это уже GET запрос. Естественно он идет без параметров.

Возможно стоит пересмотреть логику вашего приложения. Может и не надо делать перенаправление - ведь данные были получены и обработаны - достаточно только обработать ответ и сообщить об этом пользователю.

Если же такое перенаправление нужно и нужно именно сохранение данных из POST - то их можно сначала сохранить в сессии, а при следующем вызове считать. Только в этом случае не совсем понятно зачем тут нужен AJAX - можно и обычным постом форму отправить.